# how to move files to multiple folders?

Tags: c#

i have multiple folders. they are named by file extension names. (ex:- doc, dwg, jpg....etc) my list box data source have more files.(ex:- abc.dwg, beauty.jpg, arc.doc.....) i want to move doc files to doc folder, jpg files to jpg folder, dwg files to dwg folder...etc
how to do it single button click >>"create folders" button use

```
List<string> fileNames = null;
List<string> fileExtensions = null;

private void btn_list_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox_ex.Items.Clear();

    using (FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lbl_path.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
            fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath).ToList();
            fileExtensions = fileNames.Select(item => Path.GetExtension(item)
                .Replace(".", "")).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
            listBox_name.DataSource = fileNames.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();
            listBox_ex.DataSource = fileExtensions;
        }
    }
}

private void btn_CreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lbl_pathCreated.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
            fileExtensions.ForEach(item =>
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(FBD.SelectedPath, item)));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: programme interface]
[image: after click create folder button]

Comment: Could make a `List<string>` with each folder extension that you are looking for. Then `foreach(var fileType in myList) { /*Move fileType to folder*/}`

Comment: all folders are created automatically. i want to move files to each folders in automatically.

Comment: Have you considered storing your files as `FileInfo` objects instead? It would make some of the code simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you would simply call `File.Move`, and pass the full path to the existing file as the first argument, and the full path and file name for the destination.

You can build the destination path and then move the files like:

```
foreach (string file in fileNames)
{
    // Build the destination path
    var destination = Path.Combine(
        FBD.SelectedPath,                           // The root destination folder
        Path.GetExtension(file).Replace(".", ""),   // The file extension folder
        Path.GetFileName(file));                    // The file name (including extension)

    // Move the file
    File.Move(file, destination);
}
```

---

Comment: whats the mean dialog ? (dialog.SelectedPath,)

Comment: have some error. " No overload method 'combine' takes 3 arguments"

Comment: It's should, but you need a capital `C` in `Combine`...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_System_String_

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, but you could always nest two calls: `Path.Combine(FBD.SelectedPath, Path.Combine(Path.GetExtension(file).Replace(".", ""), Path.GetFileName(file)))`